# Is it better to use a separate table to store a list of values, or include the value directly in the current table?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a `jobs` table that stores information such as `title`, `department`, and `salary`. I'm wanting the user to be able to create a job using a form that has fields for the aforementioned information, as well as a field for the job category. `category` would be something like `retail`, or `IT`, for example.

I don't have any issues with the actual coding itself, but rather what the best way to design the database store the information in it. So my question is this: should I create a separate table `categories` that stores each job category, along with an ID, so that the tables would look something like this

```
categories                   jobs
+----+---------------+       +----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id | category      |       | id | title         | department  | salary | category_id |
+----+---------------+       +----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 1  | Retail        |       | 1  | Retail        | department1 | 10000  | 2           |
+----+---------------+       +----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 2  | IT            |       | 2  | IT            | department2 | 12000  | 1           |
+----+---------------+       +----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

where `category_id` is a foreign key linking to the `categories` table,

or should I do something like this, where all the information is stored in a single table:

```
jobs
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id | title         | department  | salary | category    |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 1  | Retail        | department1 | 10000  | IT          |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 2  | IT            | department2 | 12000  | Retail      |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

Which is the better option? They both seem to achieve the same result, but what are the pros and cons of doing it either way, and which way would be the more preferred way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want to store "entities" in separate tables.  In this case, `category` is a separate entity from `jobs`.

Why do you want to do this?

- There is only one row per category, so you don't have to worry about duplication -- and errors.
- There may be additional information that you want to store, such as the creation date, abbreviation, who created it, and so on.
- Properly declared foreign key constraints ensure that only valid categories are stored.
- Categories may be shared across different tables, and a separate reference table ensures that the values are consistent.

Comment: This answers my question, thank you very much :) But what about something like gender and nationality? If I think about those 2 things according to your 2nd point, it wouldn't be necessary to have a second table, but I think it would be better to have separate tables for gender and/or ethnicity based on your 4th point. But if gender is only used in 1 place, is it better to store it in the same table?

Comment: @AaronGarton . . . If you ever encountered a database where the gender column contained `'F', `'Male'`, `'X'`, `'unk'`, `'m'`, and so on, you would be less inclined to ask.